# zope.schema List - Save List of lists

Tags: plone, zope

did i misunderstand something? I want to save a list of lists, or a set of lists....

I have this

```
fcurricula = schema.List(
    title=_(u'Curricula'),
    required=False)
```

I tried to save this:

```
[
  [261, u'26-BEA', 138, 4, u'h\xf6ren, listen', 4.00, 0, u'655755sa939b9b10'],
  [261, u'26-BEA', 138, 4, u'h\xf6ren, listen', 4.00, 0, u'655755sa939b9b10']
]
```

But I get following error

```
Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 155, in _eval
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 117, in render
Module dudal.db.browser.dbimport, line 216, in dudal_fcurricula_import
Module plone.registry.registry, line 47, in __setitem__
Module plone.registry.record, line 83, in _set_value
Module zope.schema._bootstrapfields, line 182, in validate
Module zope.schema._field, line 475, in _validate
Module zope.schema._bootstrapfields, line 309, in _validate
Module zope.schema._bootstrapfields, line 248, in _validate
Module zope.schema._bootstrapfields, line 233, in _validate
Module zope.schema._bootstrapfields, line 209, in _validate
WrongType: ([[261, u'26-BEA', 138, 4, u'h\xf6ren, listen', 4.0, 0, u'655755sa939b9b10'], [261, u'26-BEA', 138, 4, u'h\xf6ren, listen', 4.0, 0, u'655755sa939b9b10']], <type 'set'>, 'value')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the value_type of the list elements. In you case also a `list`--> nested list.

You may try something like this:

```
fcurricula = schema.List(
    title=_(u'Curricula'),
    required=False)
    value_type=schema.List(...)
```

But I don't know if there is a widget for this use case.

From my point of view, the right widget for you ist a datagrid widget.
--> https://github.com/collective/collective.z3cform.datagridfield

It stores a list of dictionaries.
If you can properly name the columns in your nested list, you can use a List field with `value_type="DictRow"` with a datagridwidget.

Since you have to define a seperate schema you can also make sure, your list contains valid data.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't thought on datagridfield - but in my lists can be hundreds of lists, I don't know if datagridfiled can handle this properly. I tried TextLinesFieldWidget but this failed also...

Comment: We have a datagridwidget with several hundert entries. Of course it takes aprox 2s to render the edit view. But IMHO this is OK. This also depends on what kind of widget's your're using (columns in datagrid). If they do some DOM manipulations with Javascript the datagrid widget may not the right solution for you. But if you only have TextLines, et., this should work, or least you should try it.